# Cannot set breakpoint in chrome dev tools on executable lines

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I cannot set a breakpoint on executable lines in chrome dev tools as shown in the photo below.

I should be able to set breakpoints on lines 75 and 78 but I cannot.

I tried stopping the server, rerunning `yarn install`, and even deleting `node_modules` and restarting again.

I also tried adding code and saving but it did not fix the issue.

The browser refreshes for changes and loads the new code but still does not allow for breakpoints.

When I run the code it skips those lines, despite them being in the sourcemap.

So it's not registering the changes.

I tried clearing the browser history, cache, and resetting chrome dev tools with no success.

I also deleted the source project and recloned it only to get the same result.

The ***strange*** thing is that although the latest code is refreshing in the browser and showing up in the sourcemap within the Chrome dev tools, the code is not executing, leading me to believe it's not detecting the changes.

[image: cannot set breakpoint on executable lines in chrome dev tools]

Comment: it does not @AndyRay

Comment: Why do you want to set the breakpoints on those lines? You can put the breakpoints inside every condition because that is what you should be checking. I am not sure what you want to do by putting the breakpoints at those lines.

Comment: @collab-with-tushar-raj i want to check the values of the variables within the conditions. Regardless, I am allowed to do it on other if statements but not those. Also the logic in those statements is not being triggered meaning the code is not updating, despite it showing up in the sourcemaps. Something is not refreshing in the code or compilation process

Comment: You can still get through this issue by putting the breakpoint at line 70 or 71.

Comment: @collab-with-tushar-raj I was able to set breakpoints on the lines inside the conditionals themselves but this still doesn't solve the root issue of the sourcemap not loading in properly so I can set breakpoints on any executable line

Comment: I think as @AndyRay pointed out on the linked question, this might be due to the minification process, and the fact that the sourcemaps are being cached. You could try hard refreshing (Crtl+Shift+R) to see if it reloads the maps and everything else; if it works you could try disabling cache from the network tab in the developer console to permanently prevent the cache to cache the files. If you can't get it working, as a workaround while you find what's wrong, you could place the reserved keyword `debugger;` behind the line you need and it will behave like a breakpoint.